# Error when restarting TFTP service

Tags: networking, server, tftp

Hello i am new to using TFTP and i want to restart the service. I am currently running Ubuntu 20.04

so i entered in the command:

```
sudo service tftpd-hpa restart
```

However i receive this output:

```
`* Restarting HPA's tftpd in.tftpd`  
/srv/tftp missing, aborting.
```

Based off a tutorial I am following: [link](http://zeuzoix.github.io/techeuphoria/posts/2015/04/14/port-rt-preempt-to-kernel-3point18-for-beaglebone-black-part1/)  I should be getting a response like this:

```
no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864, leaking memory
tftpd-hpa stop/waiting
tftpd-hpa start/running, process 5082
```

Can someone help me resolve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need to make the directory `/srv/tftp`.

Look at https://wiki.debian.org/PXEBootInstall#Set_up_TFTP_server for some tips on Debian/Ubuntu's TFTP server.